# Android: Bitmap Decode java.lang.OutofMemoryError error

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory

My current android applications main functionality is to pull the frames (10fps) from a recorded video using the built in camera. Whenever the user selects the video I call my class "FrameCollector" which loops through the video and pulls the frames out and stores them into an ArrayList of Bitmaps. Having this work well for a number of days had me thinking that I was on the right track, but now I'm getting the dreaded "java.lang.OutofMemoryError"

My code is as follows:

Here it is setting the MediaMetaDataRetriever to select 10 frames per second from the video path which was passed from the main class

```
public class FrameCollector {

MediaMetadataRetriever _mmr;

double _fps;
double _duration;
long _counter = 0;
long _incrementer;

public FrameCollector(String path, Context context) 
{
    try
    {
    _mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    _mmr.setDataSource(path);

    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String fpsString = pref.getString("prefFPS", "10");
    _fps = Double.parseDouble(fpsString);
    _incrementer = (long) (1000000 / _fps);

    String stringDuration = _mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    _duration = Double.parseDouble(stringDuration) * 1000;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The below method is then adding the frame at that time to a bitmap and adding the bitmap to an arraylist of bitmaps "bitFrames"

```
public ArrayList<Bitmap> getBitmaps() 
{
    try 
    {
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitFrames = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();


        Bitmap b = _mmr.getFrameAtTime(_counter);

        while (_counter < _duration && b != null) 
        {
            bitFrames.add(b);
            _counter += _incrementer;
            b = _mmr.getFrameAtTime(_counter);
        }
        return bitFrames;   
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm thinking my issue lies with in this method. I believe I need to decode the bitmaps before I store them into the ArrayList but I'm unsure how as

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decode____(_mmr.getFrameAtTime(_counter)); 
-- Whether it be decodeStream, decodeResource, decodeFile all bring errors.
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Many Thanks,

Comment: You should check the size of every Bitmap you're saving in that array. Because you don't have many RAM available in android for your application, so if you're storing too many big bitmaps, you'll be out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Never store Bitmaps in an ArrayList unless the number of bitmaps are very small. Bitmaps take up large amounts of memory.

I've not worked with video recording before, but I would suggest you try to get a native codec library like [ffmpeg](https://github.com/tito/ffmpeg-android) to do it for you.

If you have to grab the frames yourself, however, I suggest storing them in a fixed size buffer in memory from the camera and have a background thread which pulls bitmaps from the buffer and stores it to the disk in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good to store ArrayList of Bitmaps in RAM.

Anyway if you need more than default heap size to store bitmaps in ArrayList, you can try this hack.
http://habrahabr.ru/post/139717/
It's in Russian, but I guess code is quite clear to understand.